# Does google drive rest api support searching files in Japanese?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have read documentation on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list,
but it seems that searching files against Japanese characters doesn't work properly even if I encoded file name with UTF8 encoding.
Any idears?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Drive API does support searching files in Japanese characters. 
I ran a request using the [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) resource and got a successful response. Since, i'm not sure what error you received or how your request looks.

Try the following, include the query parameter to search for the specific title of the file as such:

> title = 'テスト'

Here is the actual GET request via [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title+%3D+'%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88'
```

Try and see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm not using title = 'whatever', but title contains clause.                                              GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title+contains+'2015%E5%B9%B408%E6%9C%8805%E6%97%A5'

Comment: Sadly,A file named "2015年08月05日.jpg" doesn't work for me. which means August 5th 2015.

Comment: Exactly, querying with out extension doesn't work for me. sth like GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title+contains+'2015%E5%B9%B408%E6%9C%8805%E6%97%A5'

Comment: Try this: replace 'title' with 'fullText'. This seems to work out for me. Here is more details: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters.

Comment: We have discovered a bug where mixing latin and CJK characters in the same word leads to strange behavior. We're working to narrow down the problem and develop a fix.