# Google Drive SDK search with Chinese characters inconsistent

Tags: google-drive-api

After uploading a file to my Google Drive named `ChineseCharacters_您好這是一個小文件`, I performed a couple of queries directly using the Google Drive API found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

The `q` parameter is what's used to find files in the Drive, and I tried the following queries:

```
title contains 'ChineseCharacters_' --> Found the file
title contains '是' --> No file found
title contains '您' --> Found the file
title contains 'ChineseCharacters_您好這是一個小文件' --> No file found
```

I would expect that all of these queries would return the file that I've uploaded, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Is there something that I'm overlooking on the query, or does this seem to be a bug with the Google Drive API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug with Google Drive.  See [a related issue with Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138572/does-google-drive-rest-api-support-searching-files-in-japanese). A fix is being worked on.