# Drive Query Question q : name contains '+'

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to query all my folder files in Google Drive which their name contains the symbols
/ \ ,

when I am doing the query formula :
q : name contains '+'

and I do not get the results I need

Answer (score 0):

As per [this issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760864#comment2):

> It sounds related to a similar issue that we've already raised with the engineering team:
>
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138572/does-google-drive-rest-api-support-searching-files-in-japanese
>
> Note the issue only appears when the "contains" operator is used. Using the "=" operator for exact match works correctly, as it does in that case as well.

I gave it a test and the issue here is that searching `'\\'` and `/` either don't yield correct results or return an error.

If you have the whole file name however it does work with the `=` operator. Incedentally if the file is named `/` or `\` then `name =` /`and`name = `\\` return them respectively.